# iphone sdk - select a cell in a tableview, with code

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I would like to select a cell in a tableview, except with code before any user interaction.

Is this at all possible, a quick search through the sdk notes doesnt yield anything. Where should I look?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UITableView class, "Managing Selections" section.

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```